# C# Polymorphism constructor with distinct type

Tags: c#, constructor, polymorphism

I have a problem with my usage of Polymorphism.

Here're my example classes:

```
public class A{
    public string something;
}

public class B{
    public B(A a){
        anotherThing = a.something;
    }
    public string anotherThing;
}
```

And my question is can I have such a Polymorphism function as below?

I've found `where` can maybe make it but I have no idea how to use it.

```
public U someFunction<T, U>(T t) where T:A where U:B
{
    // do something
    var x = new U(t);
    // do something
    return x;
}
```

I searched for a while but nothing shows any concept of it.

Any help is appreciated.